# How to write to output pane from a background task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a C# extension for Visual Studio. I only have a basic understanding of the async/await mechanism and tasks usage. I am thus a bit puzzled when it comes to running some program on the background and echo its standard output to the Visual Studio output pane.

Indeed, I have written a small wrapper around the IVsOutputWindowPane object and the IDE recommends to add ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread() or ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync() calls when writing to the Visual Studio output pane. I can understand that since it is a part of the UI.

I have tried the following:

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs evt)
{
    var dte = (DTE2)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
    var outputWindow = (IVsOutputWindow)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow));
    var outputWriter = new OutputWindowMgr(dte, outputWindow);

    outputWriter.PrintLine("START");

    // Run extern program in background
    var analysis = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
        try
        {
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = bla;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = bla;
                process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = bla;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.Start();

                while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    outputWriter.PrintLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            outputWriter.PrintLine(e.Message);
        }
    });

    // It looks like waiting for the task to finish while still allowing 
    // the UI thread to process events will unlock UI thread
    while (!analysis.Wait(10))
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    outputWriter.PrintLine("STOP");
}
```

- If I keep the recommended ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread() or ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync() calls in the outputWriter.PrintLine method, it will crash.
- If I ignore them (comment them out), it will work however the order is broken: the "STOP" message will appear before the outside program has ever the chance to begin. Moreover, I am not confident it will not crash also in other situations.

What are the best practices / patterns for writing a background program's standard output (which is obviously NOT on the UI thread) to the Visual Studio output pane (which obviously IS on the UI thread)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322295/writing-to-output-build-pane-error-list-in-visual-studio-2013-with-ability-to) helps? And if we place the ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread() in first line of MenuItemCallback(), maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of the MenuItemCallback looks like the older, 2015-style. Mine, using Visual Studio 2017, does all this on async TAB functions. It adds a little complexity, but I believe this solution would work for you as well.

The key for me was using the OutputDataReceived callback on the process, and in it, creating a task that requests the UI thread to add text to the output window. I imagine there's smarter ways of doing a bunch of these things, but this works, gives progressive output, and doesn't block the UI at any point.

```
private async Task ClearOutputWindowAsync()
{
    await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);
    var dte = await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
    if (dte == null)
        return;

    EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = dte as EnvDTE80.DTE2;

    EnvDTE.OutputWindowPanes panes = dte2.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes;
    try
    {
        mOutputPane = panes.Item("My VS Extension");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        mOutputPane = panes.Add("My VS Extension");
    }

    mOutputPane.Clear();
    mOutputPane.Activate();
}

private async Task AddOutputStringAsync(string msg)
{
    await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);
    mOutputPane.OutputString(msg);
    mOutputPane.OutputString("\n");
}

private void StandardOutReceived(object proc, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs ev)
{
    package.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(() => AddOutputStringAsync(ev.Data));
}

private async Task<System.Diagnostics.Process> GetBuildProcessAsync()
{
    // this is async only because I needed to access the Solution in
    // establishing my process. It can only be read on the main thread
    // which this isn't by default
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = bla;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = bla;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = bla;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    return process;
}

private async void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mWorking)
        return;

    System.Diagnostics.Process buildProcess = await package.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync<System.Diagnostics.Process>(() => GetBuildProcessAsync());
    if (buildProcess == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    mWorking = true;

    await package.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(() => ClearOutputWindowAsync());
    string errorOut = "";

    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
        try
        {
            buildProcess.OutputDataReceived += StandardOutReceived;
            buildProcess.Start();
            buildProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            errorOut = buildProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            buildProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorOut = ex.Message;
        }
    });

    await package.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(() => AddOutputStringAsync(errorOut));
mWorking = false;
}
```